# To identify the load - from button click or refresh

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a button in my page which does some transaction in my database.

Currently, I am facing a problem:

- If I click the button it posts back the page and it goes into `button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` and  does the transaction **which is okay for me**.
- If I refresh the page , it again goes into `button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` which is not desirable.

How can I determine if the user has refreshed the page and avoid duplicating the transaction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using the referer URL? Just taking a wild guess..

So if referer URL == this page.. Do not button_Click, otherwise do.

Comment: duplicate post. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021459/update-button-keeps-updating-on-click-of-refresh-in-ie/11021578#11021578

Answer (score 0):

Do a Response.Redirect to same or another page, on submit button click event after completing the required task.

Comment: Do you mean Response.Redirect as opposed to Redirect.Redirect?